# Error after executing program at turbo c++(at output screen)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
//to generate numbers 
 void gen_data(int b[], int n) 
  { 

     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
     b[i]=rand()%101; 
   } 
   //to display numbers 
     
void disp_data(intb[],intn) 
{ 
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
  printf("%d \n",b[i]); 
} 
//insert at desired posn 
void insert(int b[], int n, int 
 elt, int pos) 
{ 
 int i; 
  for(i=n-1; i>=pos;i--) 
  b[i+1]=b[i]; 
  b[pos]=elt; 
    } 
//delete an elt at given 
  positionn 
   void delete(int b[], int n, 
 int pos) 
    { 
  int i; 
 for(i=pos+1;i<n;i++) 
  b[i-1]=b[i]; 
  } 
//driver code 
void main() 
{ 
 int a[100], pos, n=10, elt; 
  int opt; 
  clrscr(); 
  gen_data(a,n);

 while (1) 

  { 

  printf("\n 1- Insert 2-Delete 
    3-Display 4-quit\n"); 
   scanf("%d",&opt); 
   switch(opt) 
    { 
     case 1: printf(" Enter 
      positionn & elt to be 
        insertedd: "); 
         scanf("%d %d", &pos, 
          &elt); 
         insert(a,n,elt,pos); 
          n++; 
         break; 
          case 2: printf("enter 
          positionn at which 
        eltt to be deleted: "); 
        scanf("%d",pos); 
          delete(a,n,pos); 
            n--; 
         break; 
         case 3: printf("the 
         numbers are : \n"); 
       disp_data(a,n); 
       break; 
       } 
        if (opt==4) break; 
        } //end while
     }
```

when i run my code in turbo c++ it shows no errors but at output screen after excuting program and now turn to give values it will come back to codding screen. I tried to put getch() but after giving one valve it returned to codding screen. If I tried to display elements it will display random elements

Comment: Does your compiler *really don't display any error*? – `void disp_data(intb[],intn)` has invalid declaration.

Comment: Thanks  a lot I will try to correct my mistake, but some of the mistakes are done while writing code here but the int main(void) one I will correct. The problem I got is the out put screen is not staying after giving values, it will come back to codding screen

Comment: I actually wanted to use other IDE but my college uses turboc++ this year because of online classes we couldn't attend lab sections , soon we have lab exam so I wanted to execute code in turboc++.

Answer (score 0):

**You have got plenty of errors in the code:**

1. This declaration:

   ```
   void disp_data(intb[], intn)
   ```

   is clearly invalid. Adding space between `int` and `b[]` will solve this. Same with the other parameter.
2. In this declaration:

   ```
   positionn void delete (int b[], int n, int pos)
   ```

   You cannot use two types in the return statement, despite mentioning `void` in there. I think you assume you may not want to return anything since you're trying to modify the array. So, remove `positionn`.
3. This syntax (defined in the 2nd case statement):

   ```
   scanf("%d", pos);
   ```

   You forgot to introduce an ampersand sign to point-to its address. Change that into `&pos`.
4. Turbo-C is ancient. In fact, it's outdated. The `main()` must return an integer, at least zero after a successful execution. Replace the `main()` structure like this:

   ```
   int main(void) {
     .
     .
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks  a lot I will try to correct my mistake, but some of the mistakes are done while writing code here but the int main(void) one I will correct. The problem I got is the out put screen is not staying after giving values, it will come back to codding screen

Comment: I actually wanted to use other IDE but my college uses turboc++ this year because of online classes we    couldn't     attend lab sections , soon we have lab exam so I wanted to execute code in turboc++.